# Passing in URL params in axios with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, axios

I'm trying to pass in a value to the URL param after the axios call it does not go through. code below explains my problem:

```
export function fetchUser(id) {
  console.log(id) // works
 return function(dispatch, id) {
  console.log(id) // does not work
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=" + id)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_USER_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Are you sure you fired the inner function like this: fetchUser(id)(dispatch, id)?

Answer (score 2):

You have used an `id` in your `fetchUser` function as well as in your return function.

```
export function fetchUser(id) {
console.log(id) // works
 return function(dispatch) {
  console.log(id) // will work
    .......
}
```

Try removing it from your return function like shown above

Or if you're using fetchUser as a middleware function, you can remove `id` as a param in `fetchUser` and add it as a param only in your `return` function